# How to I print the value of a tag name rather than the value in Beautiful Soup 4 and Python3?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract the value `86830` from HTML source code using bs4.
Here is what I have till now:

```
page = requests.get("https://www.sunnyportal.com/Templates/PublicPage.aspx?page=1169a2ff-8f51-4ea9-ba72-316009593c62")

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
```

Now I try to extract the span id with that value:

```
pv_current = soup.find("span", attrs = {"class" : "mainValueAmount"})

print(pv_current)
```

And the output I get is

```
<span class="mainValueAmount" data-peak="164610" data-timestamp="2020-10-27T10:30:00" data-value="86830">-</span>
```

My question is, how do I extract this value of `86830`? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data-value` is an `attribute` of the `span` tag. You have to use square brackets in order to extract the attribute values from a tag. Here is how you do it:

```
value = pv_current['data-value']

print(value)
```

Output:

```
86830
```

Here is the full code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

page = requests.get("https://www.sunnyportal.com/Templates/PublicPage.aspx?page=1169a2ff-8f51-4ea9-ba72-316009593c62")

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

pv_current = soup.find("span", attrs = {"class" : "mainValueAmount"})

value = pv_current['data-value']

print(value)
```